# How to subplot a pivot table in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

a newbie programmer here. I'm trying to learn Python and I'm working with the dataset US-births which contains U.S. births data for the years 1994 to 2003.

I want to create a scatter subplots for every year (10 subplots) showing the total births per month in every year. I "wasted" one entire day trying but I can't find the right way. I got a pivot table with all the data needed, but can't put it into a plot.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/zfp8OLV[table]

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data/us_births.csv", skipinitialspace=True)
birth_per_month = df.groupby(['year','month']).births.sum().reset_index(name ='Births')

pd.pivot_table(birth_per_month, index='year', columns='month', values='Births')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, in this type of questions, never use images to show your data, give some code that will enable us to easily load that data otherwise it becomes difficult to reproduce and your chances of getting help go down drastically.

Comment: Btw, I think I solved finally!!

df = pd.read_csv("/home/datasci/PEC/prog_datasci_4/data/us_births.csv", skipinitialspace=True)
values = df.groupby(['year','month']).births.sum().reset_index(name ='Births')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,2, figsize=(15,15))
for (year, group), ax in zip(values.groupby(values.year), axes.flatten()):
    group.plot(x='month', y='Births', kind='scatter', ax=ax, title=year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your base code is right, and maybe this can help you :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("births.csv")
birth_per_month = df.groupby(['year','month']).births.sum().reset_index(name ='Births')
df = pd.pivot_table(birth_per_month, index='year', columns='month', values='Births')
```

From here we can start with the subplotting. The format in which you use a year and the corresponding data can turn into a Series in Pandas, which does not support scatter plots. instead try this :

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(5,2, figsize=(16,12))

axarr[0,0].scatter(df.columns,df.loc[1994])
axarr[0,0].set_title('1994')
axarr[0,1].scatter(df.columns,df.loc[1995])
axarr[0,1].set_title('1995')
axarr[1,0].scatter(df.columns,df.loc[1996])
axarr[1,0].set_title('1996')
axarr[1,1].scatter(df.columns,df.loc[1997])
axarr[1,1].set_title('1997')
#And so on
```

You will end up with something ressembling this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bvPx.png

Hope it is helping you

Comment: Ty sir! It has been a great help to me. It worked great.